# NetBeans GuiBuilder - adding table of objects

Tags: java, netbeans

Is there any way to add "n" Jlabels to the frame, where n is specified somewhere in code? Can I make an Array of Jlabels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can

```
JLabel [] labels = new JLabel[n];
for(int i = 0 ; i <labels.length;i++){
labels[i] = new JLabel("sometext");
//.... and other things
}
```

It's better to use `java.util.List` instead of *array*:

```
List<JLabel> labels = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0 ; i <labels.length;i++){
    labels.add(new JLabel("SomeText"));
    labels.get(i).setForeground(Color.red);
    //.... and other things
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for respond, but this is 'manualy' and I want to do this by GuiBuilder.

Comment: Ok, it seems that I have to do this without any netbeans help. Thank you for this information.